# Traefik Docker SSL Configuration With Lets Encrypt

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, lets-encrypt, traefik

Hi everyone I am trying to enable SSL in my docker-compose.yml file for my backend service.  All of my Traefik configuration is done in my docker-compose.yml file, so I may be missing a line.  Running docker-compose on this configuration works without SSL and the site is displayed properly, but it does not work when using https.  I have checked the Traefik documentation for the certResolvers and I am not sure what I am missing thanks.

```
version: "3"
networks:
    NanoWall-Net:
services:
    api:
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        labels:
            - "traefik.docker.network=NanoWall-Net"
            - "traefik.enable=true"
            - "traefik.port=5000"
            - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.rule=Host(`nanowalldocs.com`)"
            - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.tls=true"
            - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.tls.certresolver=le"
            - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.tls.domains[0].sans=nanowalldocs.com"
            - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.entrypoints=web"
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
        networks:
            - NanoWall-Net


reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.0
    # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    command:
        - "--entryPoints.web.address=:80"
        - "--entryPoints.websecure.address=:443"
        - "--entryPoints.websecure.http.tls.certResolver: le"
        - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https"
        - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure"
        - "--api.insecure=true"
        - "--api.debug=true"
        - "--api=true"
        - "--api.dashboard=true"
        - "--providers.docker=true"
        - "--providers.docker.endpoint=unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
        - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
        - "--accesslog=true"
        - "--accesslog.filepath=/var/log/traefik-access.log"
        - "--accesslog.bufferingsize=1000"
        - "--log.filePath=/var/log/traefik.log"
        - "--certificatesResolvers.le.acme.email=jamar.phillip99@gmail.com"
        - "--certificatesResolvers.le.acme.storage=acme.json"
        - "--certificatesResolvers.le.acme.httpChallenge=true"
        - "--certificatesResolvers.le.acme.httpChallenge.entryPoint=web"

    ports:
        # The HTTP port
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
        # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
        - "8080:8080"
    networks:
        - NanoWall-Net
    volumes:
        - /acme.json/etc/traefik/acme.json
         # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    restart: always
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the only issue, but you are missing a colon in your traefik volumes section. You have:

```
- /acme.json/etc/traefik/acme.json
```

I think it should be (assuming your host location is really /acme.json and not ./acme.json or in some other directory):

```
- /acme.json:/etc/traefik/acme.json
```

That said, I have also been having an issue where traefik always wants it in /acme.json, so I just put it there instead of in /etc/traefik/acme.json .